# N times function composition

Tags: ocaml

I need to write a code that composes a function, f (x), with itself N times using recursive function.

What I wrote is:

```
let f x = x + 1 (*it can be any function*)
let rec compose n f x = if n = 0 then 
   "Can't compose anymore" 
else compose (n-1) f (f x);;
```

which is obviously not right. I know the code is not finished, but I do not know how to continue. Am I on the right path or not? Can you tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Is there code missing? An expression of `let ..... in` defines a variable to be used in the next line. But your last line ends with `in`. You should use the OCaml top-level to at least confirm that your syntax is correct. That's probably why you got downvoted.

Comment: There is no code missing. I just do not know how to continue so I put down what I wrote so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path. Based on the requirements, I would try to start from those equations:

```
compunere 1 f x == f x
```

The above says that applying `f` once to `x` is exactly the same as doing `(f x)`.

```
compunere 2 f x == f (f x)
```

Likewise, applying `f` twice should compute `f (f x)`. If you replace `(f x)` by a call to `compunere`, you have:

```
compunere 2 f x == f (f x) = f (compunere 1 f x)
```

The general pattern of recursion seems to be:

```
compunere n f x == f (compunere (n - 1) f x)
```

Note that the most general type of `f` is `a -> b`, but when `f` is called again with a value of type `b`, that means that `a` and `b` should be the same type, and so `f` really is an endomorphism, a function of type `a -> a`. That is the case for N >= 1, but in degenerate case of N=0, you could have a different behaviour.

Applying `f` zero time to `x` could mean "return x", which means that `compunere` *could* theoretically return a value of type `a` for zero, for any `f` being a `a -> b` function, `a` and `b` possibly distinct; you could distinguish both cases with more code, but here we can simply let the typechecker  enforce the constraint that `a = b` in all cases and have an uniform behaviour. You can also make 0 invalid (like negative numbers) by throwing an exception (negative applications could theoretically be postitive applications of the inverse function, but you cannot compute that when knowing nothing about f; f could be non-invertible).

Your code is a little bit different:

```
compunere 3 f x == (compunere 2 f (f x))
                == (compunere 1 f (f (f x)))
                == (compunere 0 f (f (f (f x))))
...
```

The advantage of your approach is that the recursive call to `compunere` is directly giving the result for the current computation: it is in tail position  which allows the compiler to perform tail-call elimination.

When you reach N=0, the value locally bound `x` gives the result you want. Here, for N=0 as an input, the only natural interpretation is also to return `x`.